# Parsed JSON ListView and ImageView

Tags: android, json, listview, picasso

I would like to ask your help to add an image in a listview with json using picasso

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting the related idioms
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {

    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(


            ListResult.this, idiomsList,
            R.layout.list_view, new String[] { TAG_NM_FANTASIA, TAG_CEP, TAG_ENDERECO, TAG_FONE1, TAG_FONE2, TAG_FONE3
            , TAG_FAX, TAG_WEB_SITE, TAG_EMAILS, TAG_FACEBOOK, TAG_TWITTER, TAG_GOOGLEMAS, TAG_SELO300, TAG_MAPS, TAG_URL_MAPS, TAG_SOBRE_EMPRESA
            , TAG_APRESENTACAO, TAG_DESCRICAO, TAG_LOGOMARCA, },
            new int[] { R.id.txtNome, R.id.txtCep, R.id.txtEndreco, R.id.txtFone1, R.id.txtFone2, R.id.txtFone3, R.id.txtFax
                    , R.id.txtWebSite, R.id.txtEmails, R.id.txtFacebook, R.id.txtTwitter
                    , R.id.txtGoogleMas, R.id.txtSelo300, R.id.txtMaps
                    , R.id.txtUrlMaps, R.id.txtSobreEmpresa, R.id.txtApresentacao, R.id.txtDescricao, R.id.txtImg, });

    // updating listview
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I need to add an image in listview with the image coming from the json

Comment: You have to create a custom Adapter instead of using `SimpleAdapter`. You can make your own class that extends ArrayAdapter and override the getView() method to inflate which ever types of views you want to show. In your case it sounds like an ImageView

Comment: Can you give me an example? I am new in android programming, I do not quite understand

Comment: I made a video tutorial that covers how to parse xml data into a listview. https://youtu.be/40mYDQkK44A If you follow along with that you should have enough knowledge afterward to re-purpose it to work with JSON data.